# uwsgi + apache + django

Tags: django, apache, sockets, uwsgi

I am running apache (mod_uwsgi) with uwsgi. in settings i have unix socket pointing to /var/uwsgi/ . I am also pointing to this socket from apache vhost. If i try to access this vhost, i got error (in apache log):

apache log:

```
uwsgi: unable to connect to uWSGI server: Permission denied
```

uwsgi config:

```
 <uwsgi>
            <pythonpath>/home/user/django_projects/project/</pythonpath>
            <master/>
            <no-orphans/>
            <processes>1</processes>
            <optimize>0</optimize>
            <home>/home/user/Envs/project/</home>
            <limit-as>128</limit-as>
            <chmod-socket>664</chmod-socket>

            <gid>www-data</gid>
            <pidfile>/var/uwsgi/project.pid</pidfile>
            <socket>/var/uwsgi/project.sock</socket>
            <wsgi-file>/home/user/django_projects/project/deploy/wsgi-sites/production.py</wsgi-file>
            <daemonize>/var/uwsgi/project.log</daemonize>
            <chdir>/home/user/django_projects/project/</chdir>
    </uwsgi>
```

and apache config:

```
<Location />
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    SetHandler uwsgi-handler
    uWSGISocket /var/uwsgi/project.sock
</Location>
```

what am i missing? I also tried changing chmod socket to 777..no success..

Comment: may be you have to make sure that apache module mod_uwsgi is enable first.

Comment: ok, now i run it over tcp (like uWSGISocket 127.0.0.1:20000) and over supervisor, so <deamonize> must go away..

Answer (score 0):

I run mod_wsgi with django, but consider adding a Directory block to the Apache config.

```
<Directory /var/uwsgi/>
        Options All
</Directory>
```

And if that works, make the "All" statement more specific to your needs.